# Difference between installing service in Windows Container and Windows Server 2016?

Tags: docker, service, windows-server-2016

I have a service application that will install correctly in Windows Server 2016 Standard using the following command:

```
PS C:\Service> c:\\mysvc\\mysvc.exe -install
Service installed successfully
```

If I run the same thing when in a Dockerfile using:

```
RUN c:\\mysvc\\mysvc.exe -install
```

I get the following output:

> The command 'cmd /S /C c:\svc\mysvc.exe -install' returned a
>   non-zero code: 3221225781

I'm not sure why it is behaving differently, or where I could check to get some better ideas as to the cause of the error.

Answer (score 1):

A useful tip for debugging this sort of issue is to run the base image in an interactive container, follow the steps for your Dockerfile and see if you get some more useful output.

In your case, something like:

```
docker run -it --name temp microsoft/windowsservercore cmd
```

Then in another command on the Windows host:

```
docker cp mysvc.exe temp:c:/mysvc.exe
```

And back in the interactive container run `c:\mysvc -install`.

If the output doesn't help, you could add some more details to your question here - the Dockerfile and some info about the Windows service.

Comment: I tried as you suggested, and when I run the c:\mysvc.exe -install the command just returns, no output, no running process is created, no service is created, no errors reported, nothing. It's weird.

Comment: Okay - what's your `FROM` image? And does the exe have any switches for verbose install?

Comment: Best guess is that your service has some dependency that's not there or not enabled in the Server Core base image, but unless you can get more info from the exe it's going to be hard to figure out.

Comment: I actually figured out at least part of the problem. It appears that, among others, Server Core 2016 doesn't have the following dll's: opengl32.dll, oledlg.dll, glu32.dll and ddraw.dll, whereas Server 2016 standard does. Copying those dll's from Server 2016 standard over to my Server Core VM lets me install the service. I didn't see the error message in my Server Core container, because it actually pops up a Message Dialog to tell you it can't find them, which the container doesn't seem to support.

Comment: Hmm. They all sound like UI components, so I'd question why they're a dependency for a Windows Service. Also - not sure of the licensing implications copying DLLs around.